# Pre-loading specific machines with differently sized queues with simmer package

Tags: r, simulation, event-simulation

I have a relatively complex simmer simulation in which I want to start with a queue pre-loaded. I know you can preload a queue by simply adding a generator at t=0, but as far as I understand that will start every pre-loaded job from the first machine in the process. I would like to have it where I can specify the size of the queue at each machine prior to starting the simulation (imagine a 5 step manufacturing process where there are already 2 jobs waiting at machine 2, but 5 jobs waiting at machine 3 left over from the previous day).

I have already defined a trajectory (called manu_traj) with the necessary steps and an environment (called plant) with the necessary resources.

Is there any way to do this? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO, Tom Bruce! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.